# Nodejs event emitter implementation in Nextjs 13 or 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next.js13

How do i make nodejs event emitter object listen to emitted events globally within my nextjs13 application just like in normal nodejs environment?

I have a file *post.js* where a user creates a new post. I want to promptly return the response back to the user, emit an event where a handler function will listen to the emitted event in another file & perform some other tasks in the background like updating post tags count and then finally  emitting an sse(server sent event) to client app to notify other connected clients.

First of all, i created a file known as *eventEmitter.js*  where I created a single instance to be used within my application below;

```
    //eventEmitter.js

    import { EventEmitter } from 'node:events';

    const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter({captureRejections: true})

    export default eventEmitter;
```

```
    //post.js
  
    import eventEmitter from './eventEmitter'
  
    const insertPost = async() => {
       // perform db post insert
       
       //emit an event to be listened to perform a background task
       eventEmitter.emit("PING", "hello world");
       
       //return 
       return {id: 1, title: 'hello' }
   }
   

   insertPost()
   
   
    // this only works when the listener is in the same file with the emitted event
   eventEmitter.on("PING", (ev) => {
        console.log(ev)
   });
```

```
    //listener.js
  
    import eventEmitter from './eventEmitter'
    // this doesn't work i.e the event is not captured in the file
   eventEmitter.on("PING", (ev) => {
        console.log(ev)
   });
```

```
 //route.js
  export function GET(request: Request) {
       const responseStream = new TransformStream();
       const writer = responseStream.writable.getWriter();
       const encoder = new TextEncoder();
       //... other code
      
       // this doesn't work i.e the event is not captured in the file
      eventEmitter.on("PING", (ev) => {
        console.log(ev)
     });
     
     // my streaming logic
}
```

My question is, how do i listen to the emitted event in other files like **listener.js** and **route.js** files  other than just **post.js** file?

I want to listen to the emitted events globally within my nextjs app

The above works seamlessly in a nodejs environment and i expected it to work in nextjs environment too.

*PS:* I'm using nextjs App Router

Please help.